# Pulling first level relationship via Standard Controller

Tags: visualforce

If you try to test the following visualforce page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" >
     <apex:repeat var="contact" value="{!record.Contacts}">
        <apex:outputText value="{!contact.Name}">example</apex:outputText>
    </apex:repeat> 
</apex:page>
```

You get an error that says:

`SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Account.Contacts`

Why is this not possible and what is the correct approach? Shall we use custom controllers or controller extensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this, you just need to refer to the `Account` differently. It works like this:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" >
    <apex:repeat var="contact" value="{!Account.Contacts}">
        <apex:outputText value="{!contact.Name}">example</apex:outputText>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_std_access_data.htm

> For example, a page that uses the Account standard controller can use
>   {!account.name} to return the value of the name field on the account
>   that is currently in context.

Comment: Thanks :) is there a specific reason for it?

Comment: Honestly, I didn't even know that you could write it as record.Contacts. I've only ever seen it documented as Account.Contacts. Maybe using record is a legacy method?